# Uncrustify: Space between function name and brace at end of line

Tags: objective-c, formatting, uncrustify

If I have a function like this:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self){

    }
    return self;
}
```

and I want uncrustify to output this:

```
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){

    }
    return self;
}
```

What options would I need to set? I can't seem to find a brace option for the end of the function name. I've noticed that it will add a space there, but I can't find the option that's doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like

`sp_fparen_brace remove`

Should do it according to this: http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/config.txt